# How can I better organize my VueJS and VueX project to allow a dialog box with a cancel feature?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is there a standard way to edit object locally in a dialog box component's state and then commit them to the main VueX store once a save operation is done?

I'm working on a front end to edit a complex object. There's a piece that is a list of object and I've created a component to edit them. My structure looks something like this.

Here's the sub object component.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-text-field v-model="subObject.height" />
      ... many more elements ...
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn @click="save()">Save</v-btn>
      <v-btn @click="cancel()">Cancel</v-btn>
  </v-card>
  
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditSubObject",
  props: ['index'],
  computed: {
    subObject () {
      return this.$store.state.mainObject.subObjects[this.index]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save () {
      this.$emit('close')
    },
    cancel () {
      this.$emit('close')
    },
}
</script>
```

Here's the usage of this page in the main object.

```
<template>
  ... other parts of the main object ...

  <v-row v-for="(obj,index) in subObjects" :key="index" v-bind:index="index">
    <v-btn icon @click="showDialog=true">
    <v-dialog v-model="showDialog">
      <edit-sub-object 
        v-bind:index="index"
        @save="showDialog=false"
        @close="showDialog=false"/>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>

  .. other parts of the main object ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "EditMainObject",
  computed {
    subObjects () {
      return this.$store.state.mainObject.subObjects
      // other typo "}"
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

What happens is even if you press 'cancel' the main object is still edited. This is pretty obvious why. I'm binding in the object from the main VueX store by reference into the v-model of my edit v-text-field.

So one of the things I tried was to create an updateSubObject mutation in my VueX store. It looked like this

```
updateSubObject(state, {index, obj}) {
    state.mainObject[index] = obj
}
```

From there, I did a deep copy of the sub object in my component, edited that, and then called the method on save. So I made these updates to my sub object component. First remove the computed subObject and use this data

```
data () {
  return {
    subObject: _.cloneDeep(this.$store.state.mainObject.subObjects[this.index])
  }
}
```

Next update the save method to to call my VueX mutation and cancel simply omits the update call.

```
save () {
  this.$store.commit('updateSubObject', {index: this.index, obj: this.subObject})
  this.$emit('close')
}
```

This actually never causes an update to the object and I'm pretty confused as to why. Furthermore, there's never a reset of the internal object to the component. So if I click to edit it, make changes, cancel, then edit it again, I see the changes I previously made which is not what I want. I'd like it to be cleared and deep copied again.

I am pretty sure I'm misusing VueX and probably need to use a life cycle hook to refresh and deep clone the sub object but I've tried created, mounted, beforeCreated, and beforeMounted and I don't see any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being that when I assign the new localCopy to the global store, it was an object, with references to fields that were continually bound to the v-model of the the sub component. I needed to not only cloneDeep the initial object, but also cloneDeep the copy that I place into the global store or it remains tied.

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve it is just taking a look at "mapState method in vuex." Because when you update then you must call  it again and the code is:

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

// ...
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    subObjects: state => state.mainObject.subObjects
  }),

  // and the others
}
// ...
```

in this way vuex will change the value auto in the components.

And do not forget that if you want to change value in Vuex the best way to doing it is : "using mutations"

```js
//getting this.index of subObjects

<... v-model="subObjects[index]" ...>
```

Comment: This does the same thing. mapState is just syntactic sugar around updates and reads from the Vuex store. The error was that I was storing an object with references. I answered my own question finally today. See that for details. Thanks for taking the time to help though.